# Powershell to wait a macro to be executed in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I'm using a very simple powershell to open a excel file, run a macro and save the file.

The macro is basically the REFRESH ALL button under the DATA tab.

My issue is that the excel hung in the Save stage because the REFRESH ALL never gets completed.

If I add a PAUSE between the commands. I can properly progress without problems.

```
clear

$file = "\\website\folder\file.xlsm"

$displayname = $File.split("\")[$File.split("\").count-1]

Write-Host "Creating Excel Instance for $displayname"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

Write-Host "Opening $displayname"

$Excel.Visible = $True

$Excel.StatusBar = "Opening the file... Please be patient..." 

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file)

Write-Host "Running Refresh Query"

$Excel.StatusBar = $False

$Excel.Run("Refresh_All")

PAUSE ## This pause is needed in order to wait the Macro to happen

Write-Host "Saving $displayname" 

$Workbook.Save()

Write-Host "Close Excel Instance"

$Excel.Quit()
```

If tried read the $excel.Ready status... but that is always ready...

I'm looking for a way to read the status bar and recognize the RUNNING BACKGROUND QUERY message and save the file when that gets completed.

Any hint?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution...

Solution: "Go to the data tab, click connections in the connections group, click on EVERY connection and click properties, un-check the box that says "enable background refresh"." (tylerlohman@gmail.com , pcreview, 2013).